# Создание дочернего окна PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Помогите создать дочернее окно, которое при закрытии основного закроется вместе с ним, само дочернее окно должно внешне отличаться.

К сожалению, знаю только как создавать обычное окно.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Lab 2-3")

        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)

        self.setGeometry(590, 300, 480, 215)
        self.setStyleSheet("background : white;")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window_2(QMainWindow):                             # !!! QMainWindow
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)                         # !!! parent
        self.setWindowTitle("Window_2")
        self.resize(200, 215)
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Lab 2-3")
        self.setGeometry(590, 300, 480, 215)
        self.setStyleSheet("background : white;")
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
  
        self.button = QPushButton('Создать второе окно')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.create_window) 
        
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.button)
        
    def create_window(self):
        self.window = Window_2(self)                        # !!! self
        self.window.show()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]